# How to arrange tabbarview's height?

Tags: flutter

```
TabBarView(
                          controller: tabController,
                          children: [
                            MarkdownBody(
                              data: currentTreatment.treatmentDescription,
                              styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
                                p: TextStyle(fontSize: 16 * w),
                                h4: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 19 * w,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Query(
                                options: QueryOptions(
                                    document: gql(hospitalsGraphQL)),
                                builder: (QueryResult result,
                                    {fetchMore, refetch}) {
                                  if (result.hasException) {
                                    return Text(
                                        result.exception.toString());
                                  }
                                  if (result.isLoading) {
                                    return Center(
                                      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                                        curve: Curves.decelerate,
                                        lineWidth: 12 * h,
                                        progressColor:
                                            Colors.green.shade400,
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            Colors.green.shade200,
                                        radius: 50 * h,
                                        percent: 1,
                                        circularStrokeCap:
                                            CircularStrokeCap.round,
                                        animation: true,
                                        center: Image.asset(
                                          "lib/images/Medicte_cropped.png",
                                          height: 60 * h,
                                        ),
                                        animationDuration: 1000,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                  final hospitalList =
                                      result.data?['hospitals'];
                                  
                                  return HospitalsByTreatments(
                                    currentTreatment: currentTreatment,
                                    hospitalList: hospitalList,
                                  );
                                }),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: heightContainer,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: PageView.builder(
                                        controller: pageController,
                                        itemCount: listLengthCalculator(
                                            currentTreatment
                                                .medicte_hotels.length),
                                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                            int index) {
                                          return Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                horizontal: 6 * w),
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                ClipRRect(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          15),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            right: 12 * w,
                                                            left: 12 * w,
                                                            top: 12 * h),
                                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                                    width: 400 * w,
                                                    height:
                                                        (heightContainer -
                                                                35) /
                                                            2,
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        CircleAvatar(
                                                          radius: 65 * h,
                                                          backgroundImage:
                                                              NetworkImage(
                                                            "https://admin.medicte.ca${currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2]["hotelPicture"]["formats"]["small"]["url"]}",
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 10 * h,
                                                        ),
                                                        Expanded(
                                                          child: Column(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                    .center,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Text(
                                                                  currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index *
                                                                          2]
                                                                      [
                                                                      "hotelTitle"],
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                          .bold,
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          18 * w)),
                                                              SizedBox(
                                                                  height:
                                                                      10 *
                                                                          h),
                                                              Text(
                                                                currentTreatment
                                                                        .medicte_hotels[
                                                                    index *
                                                                        2]["hotelDescription"],
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        13 *
                                                                            w),
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10 * h,
                                                ),
                                                if (index * 2 + 1 + 1 <
                                                    currentTreatment
                                                        .medicte_hotels
                                                        .length)
                                                  ClipRRect(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius
                                                            .circular(15),
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      padding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.all(
                                                              12 * h),
                                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                                      width: 400 * w,
                                                      height:
                                                          (heightContainer -
                                                                  35) /
                                                              2,
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          CircleAvatar(
                                                            radius: 65 * h,
                                                            backgroundImage:
                                                                NetworkImage(
                                                              "https://admin.medicte.ca${currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2 + 1]["hotelPicture"]["formats"]["small"]["url"]}",
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(
                                                            height: 10 * h,
                                                          ),
                                                          Expanded(
                                                            child: Column(
                                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                  CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                      .center,
                                                              children: [
                                                                Text(
                                                                    currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2 +
                                                                            1]
                                                                        [
                                                                        "hotelTitle"],
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        fontWeight:
                                                                            FontWeight.bold,
                                                                        fontSize: 18 * w)),
                                                                SizedBox(
                                                                    height:
                                                                        10 *
                                                                            h),
                                                                Text(
                                                                  currentTreatment
                                                                      .medicte_hotels[index *
                                                                          2 +
                                                                      1]["hotelDescription"],
                                                                  overflow:
                                                                      TextOverflow
                                                                          .fade,
                                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                                      fontSize:
                                                                          13 * w),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }),
                                  ),
                                  SmoothPageIndicator(
                                      controller: pageController,
                                      count: listLengthCalculator(
                                          currentTreatment
                                              .medicte_hotels.length),
                                      effect: ScrollingDotsEffect(
                                        activeStrokeWidth: 2.6,
                                        activeDotScale: 1.3,
                                        maxVisibleDots: 5,
                                        radius: 8 * h,
                                        spacing: 10 * w,
                                        dotHeight: 12 * w,
                                        dotWidth: 12 * w,
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

There are 3 different tabview with different heights, one of them is a query, as you can see. What should I do to get children's heights, and arrange of tab bar view's height. On the other hand, I used AutoScaleTabBarView on pub.dev but it doesn't solve my problem It arranges it's height when tab is changed, but my second 2 tab is a query which it takes time to fetch data, when it is on process there is a circular progress indicator, then the result is printing but it doesn't show like in the picture

Answer (score 0):

Try do Stream and use `IndexedStack()`:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final List<Widget> pages;
  late final StreamController<int> _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
    pages = [
      MarkdownBody(
        data: currentTreatment.treatmentDescription,
        styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
          p: TextStyle(fontSize: 16 * w),
          h4: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 19 * w,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              color: Colors.grey.shade700),
        ),
      ),
      Query(
          options: QueryOptions(
              document: gql(hospitalsGraphQL)),
          builder: (QueryResult result,
              {fetchMore, refetch}) {
            if (result.hasException) {
              return Text(
                  result.exception.toString());
            }
            if (result.isLoading) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                  curve: Curves.decelerate,
                  lineWidth: 12 * h,
                  progressColor:
                  Colors.green.shade400,
                  backgroundColor:
                  Colors.green.shade200,
                  radius: 50 * h,
                  percent: 1,
                  circularStrokeCap:
                  CircularStrokeCap.round,
                  animation: true,
                  center: Image.asset(
                    "lib/images/Medicte_cropped.png",
                    height: 60 * h,
                  ),
                  animationDuration: 1000,
                ),
              );
            }
            final hospitalList =
            result.data?['hospitals'];

            return HospitalsByTreatments(
              currentTreatment: currentTreatment,
              hospitalList: hospitalList,
            );
          }),
      SizedBox(
        height: heightContainer,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: pageController,
                  itemCount: listLengthCalculator(
                      currentTreatment
                          .medicte_hotels.length),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                      int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 6 * w),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(
                                15),
                            child: Container(
                              padding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 12 * w,
                                  left: 12 * w,
                                  top: 12 * h),
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              width: 400 * w,
                              height:
                              (heightContainer -
                                  35) /
                                  2,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 65 * h,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                    NetworkImage(
                                      "https://admin.medicte.ca${currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2]["hotelPicture"]["formats"]["small"]["url"]}",
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10 * h,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment
                                          .center,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                            currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index *
                                                2]
                                            [
                                            "hotelTitle"],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                    .bold,
                                                fontSize:
                                                18 * w)),
                                        SizedBox(
                                            height:
                                            10 *
                                                h),
                                        Text(
                                          currentTreatment
                                              .medicte_hotels[
                                          index *
                                              2]["hotelDescription"],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize:
                                              13 *
                                                  w),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10 * h,
                          ),
                          if (index * 2 + 1 + 1 <
                              currentTreatment
                                  .medicte_hotels
                                  .length)
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius
                                  .circular(15),
                              child: Container(
                                padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(
                                    12 * h),
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                width: 400 * w,
                                height:
                                (heightContainer -
                                    35) /
                                    2,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 65 * h,
                                      backgroundImage:
                                      NetworkImage(
                                        "https://admin.medicte.ca${currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2 + 1]["hotelPicture"]["formats"]["small"]["url"]}",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10 * h,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                            .center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                              currentTreatment.medicte_hotels[index * 2 +
                                                  1]
                                              [
                                              "hotelTitle"],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                  FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 18 * w)),
                                          SizedBox(
                                              height:
                                              10 *
                                                  h),
                                          Text(
                                            currentTreatment
                                                .medicte_hotels[index *
                                                2 +
                                                1]["hotelDescription"],
                                            overflow:
                                            TextOverflow
                                                .fade,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize:
                                                13 * w),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            SmoothPageIndicator(
                controller: pageController,
                count: listLengthCalculator(
                    currentTreatment
                        .medicte_hotels.length),
                effect: ScrollingDotsEffect(
                  activeStrokeWidth: 2.6,
                  activeDotScale: 1.3,
                  maxVisibleDots: 5,
                  radius: 8 * h,
                  spacing: 10 * w,
                  dotHeight: 12 * w,
                  dotWidth: 12 * w,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
        initialData: 0,
        stream: _pageController.stream.distinct(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: [IndexedStack(index: snapshot.data!, children: pages),
TabBar(
      tabs: [Text('MarkdownBody'), Text('Query'), Text('SmoothPageIndicator')],
      onTap: (index) {
        _pageController.add(index);
      },
    ),])
          );
        });
  }
}
```